# What is this specific line of C# code relating to arrays is doing?

Tags: c#

I'm doing some self paced learning and ran into this line of code that I'm not 100% certain I understand.

This is for a C# problem I'm working on. I know that the line is declaring the variable 'array' and saying that it is a new instance of this object. I'm confused about:

- Is this stating that the array will contain characters as its' data type?
- How the `.Length` operator being used here? Is this saying that the data that each cell is storing is number of characters, and not the characters themselves, in each cell of the array?

Code:

```
var array = new char[name.Length]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the `char` part shows that the element type of the array is `char`. The equivalent code with an explicitly typed variable would be:

```
char[] array = new char[name.Length];
```

In terms of the `Length` property, that's just used to determine the size of the array. That's what the value within the `[]` always means when creating an array. For example, this creates an integer array with 5 elements:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

It may help to clarify things for your example if we separate things out:

```
int length = name.Length;
char[] array = new char[length];
```

Is that clearer to you?

The [arrays section of the Microsoft C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) can give more details about arrays in general.